# Gallery images to be displayed based on a criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of images with names like NH-1,NH-2,NH-3,... and another set NS-1,NS-2,NS-3,.... displayed as gallery images with three images in a row. Now, I will create a div at the left hand side that displays the links to categories. Say this div has categories NH and NS . Suppose when I click on NH, the images in the gallery should get filtered and only images with prefix NH should be displayed and when I click on NS all images with NS as prefix should be displayed.By default if nothing is clicked, then all images should be displayed. How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a javascript

```
function showImages(var type) {
  // Based on the type of image, you can display the images as gallery

  // For each image element you want to add you can use the following code. Define a CSS class called as .thumbnail to show the image gallery in thumbnail size.
  $('#content').prepend('<img id="imgid" src="imgfile.jpg" class="thumbnail"/>')
}
```

Call the showImages('') method in the onlcick event of the link.

Comment: If all are jpg images, can I do the filter

Comment: Yest you can do the filter, even if the img extension is jpg.

Comment: Changed the file extension to JPG.

Answer (score 0):

You have got your data structured only, just need to consider the approach

first of you need to catch the click function on the categories

```
$("category selector").click(function(){
//logic here to call a function to show images and pass prefix
showImageWithPrefix(get NH or NS,send image count accordingly);
});

function showImageWithPrefix(prefix,Count)
{
//now you can show the images using a for loop just by appending `'-`' and
 `image extension` to the `image name prefix`
}
```